# I would like to replace in python without overlaping

Tags: python

I am a beginner using python to do some scripts. I would like to replace in my files `"FQ_PARAMS"` by `"FQ_PARAMS_PRICING"`. It works well but the problem is that in some file I already have this `"FQ_PARAMS_PRICING"`. So it become `"FQ_PARAMS_PRICING_PRICING"`. I would like to know if there is a way to do it without overlapping.

Here is my code:

```
for file in dirs:
   if file.endswith('.play'):
        fileComplete=dirPath+"/"+file
        with open(fileComplete, "r") as myfile:
            chaine=myfile.read()
            result=re.sub(r'FQ_PARAMS',r'FQ_PARAMS_PRICING',chaine)
            with open(fileComplete,"w") as fichier:
                fichier.write(result)
```

Comment: `re.sub(r'\bFQ_PARAMS\b',r'FQ_PARAMS_PRICING',chaine)` if `FQ_PARAMS` is a word (fails if continues with underscore)

Comment: Is there an anchoring context, to can rely on, say these tokens always surrounded by a space, or inside quotes? As a negative lookahead only helps, if you can excluded, what follows, so e.g, could there be occurences of FQ_PARAMS_FOO (which for now and with Willems answer would still receive a _PRICING injection. (As @Jean-FrançoisFabre tries to exclude following underscores ...)

Comment: Thank for this quick and general answer. It solves the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *negative lookahead*. So the regex now reads:

```
r'FQ_PARAMS(?!_PRICING)'
```

```
for file in dirs:
   if file.endswith('.play'):
        fileComplete=dirPath+"/"+file
        with open(fileComplete, "r") as myfile:
            chaine=myfile.read()
            result=re.sub(r'FQ_PARAMS(?!_PRICING)',r'FQ_PARAMS_PRICING',chaine)
            with open(fileComplete,"w") as fichier:
                fichier.write(result)
```

*Lookahead* looks ahead (without consuming the characters), and *negative* lookahead adds a constraint that it should *not* see `_PRICING` when it looks ahead. Only these items are matched.